# How to ask for what an object is called?

Tags: перевод

This morning I asked a woman in a shop `Как его зовут?`, referring to some toothpaste. She replied "Aquafresh". Is it perhaps that `зовут` specifically connotes asking for something's *name*, rather than just the word for it? Is there a better way to say it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When referring some nonliving object, it's better to ask:

- To get the name (title in the case of goods) of a particular object:

  > Как это называется?
- To get the type (class, kind) of an object:

  > Что это?

Answer (score 3):

With objects, you ask ***Как это называется?*** (Note also that *это*, rather than *оно*, is the default "it" pronoun for objects; you use the pronoun of the object's respective grammatical gender when you've already referred to that object.)

*Как его/её зовут?* is even more specific than that, it's for asking about some*one*’s name, so asking it about something like toothpaste sounds whimsical. You can ask it about an animal, though.

Answer (score 1):

> "Как его зовут?" = "What is his name?"

If I heard "Как его зовут?" referring to a thing in a supermarket, I would understand it as "How the mascot of this thing is called?" if there was a picture of a super-hero or an animal on the box, or you were asking for the name of the advertising actor whose photo is depicted. If there were no animated hero or a photo on the thing, I just would not parse the question (or, possibly, would guess you are asking about the name of the CEO of the company that produces the thing?).

Comment: That's very helpful, thanks. Maybe the closest english equivalent would be asking "What is *he* called?" ?

Comment: @Jack M roughly like "what is his name?"

Answer (score 1):

The most comfortable form for the person you're asking would be:

"Как называется эта <вещь>?"

Как называется эта зубная паста? Как называется этот город? Как называется то дерево?

This way you specify the thing which name you like to know.

Comment: It sounded to me like the OP didn't **know** the name of the object and was attempting to elicit that exact piece of information by asking the question.

Comment: @MrWonderful then OP can surely ask "Как называется эта вещь?"

Comment: Ah, I see.  Google gave "As the name of this <item>?" for the translation of your first answer.  I thought it sounded awkward.  When I remove the angle brackets, it came out perfectly to what you suggested.  My bad.  Thanks!